# libnfc cannot find NFC Device

Tags: kali-linux

I have an ACR122U-A9 NFC Reader that I am trying to have connect to Kali Linux (that is running as a Virtual Machine on Windows 10).

However I am having some issue with having `nfc-list` or `nfc-scan-device` recognize this device.

The first bit of trouble is that I see the device showing up as a couple removable devices.

[image]

If I connect the 'Advanced Card ACR122U PICC Interface' device and run `nfc-scan-device -v`, it says "1 NFC Device Found:" but does not provide any information on the device. `pcsc_scan` does not return anything for this device.

If I connect the 'Shared ACS ACR122 0' device, `pcsc_scan` is able to recognize Reader 0 as 'VMware Virtual USB CCID 00 00' but `nfc-scan-device -v` returns no NFC Devices found.

What am I doing wrong? I installed the `libacsccid1_1.1.6-1~bpo8+1_amd64.deb` driver from /ACS-Unified-PKG-Lnx-116-P/acsccid_linux_bin-1.1.6/debian/jessie/ (from ACS' driver website)

Comment: Does the reader work properly if you don't have a virtual machine in the way?

Comment: @Mark: Yes it does with the windows-equivalent programs